# How can I test a function created during instantiation of an object?

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, mocking

I'm trying to write a test to make sure my program generates a specific output given a specific input. I've successfully mocked the input I want to test, but I haven't been able to mock the output function. I left a couple comments with things I've tried and their errors. How can I make these tests work?

This is my test:

```
from src_dir import my_class

    class Mock_Dependency:
        def __init__( self ):
            pass
        def print_stuff( self, stuff ):
            ##return MagicMock() - does not have attribute called
            return stuff

    @fixture
    @patch('src_dir.dependency.Dependency, Mock_Dependency)
    def subject():
        return my_class.My_Class()

    ##@patch('subject.print_stuff', MagicMock) - No module named subject
    ##@patch('my_class.My_Class.print_stuff', MagicMock) - does not have attribute print stuff
    def test_print_stuff_was_called( subject ):
        assert subject.print_stuff.called
    def test_print_stuff_printed( subject ):
        assert subject.print_stuff == 'a word'
```

This is my class:

```
from dependency import Dependency

class My_Class:
  def __init__( self ):
    self.print_stuff = Dependency.print_stuff()
  def run( self ):
    self.print_stuff('a word')
```

Answer (score 1):

A solution to my problem was to mock `print_stuff` inside of the test function after the fixture `subject` was received:

```
def test_print_stuff_was_called( subject ):
    with patch.object(subject, 'print_stuff') as mock:
        subject.run()
    mock.assert_called_with('a word') # pass
    mock.assert_called_with('anything else') # fail
```